# Sign-in link does not appear

Tags: authentication

This is rather strange.

The Sign-In link (upper right corner) has disappeared from an entire SharePoint web application.

Anyone run into this situation before?

Comment: Has the markup been removed from the master page?

Comment: have you check its not a 64 bit browser.

Answer (score 1):

This link can be helpful for you.
http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2013/archive/2012/11/07/how-to-show-sign-in-as-different-user-menu-item-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx

Step 1:

Go to the welcome.ascx file in 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\CONTROLTEMPLATES':

Step 2:

Add the code below to the welcome.ascx file in whichever place you prefer (i.e., in what order you want the link to appear).

" 
Description="<%$Resources:wss,personalactions_loginasdifferentuserdescription%>" 
MenuGroupId="100" 
Sequence="100"  UseShortId="true" />

Step 3:

Go to your site and click Refresh, at which point you you will see that Sign in as Different User is now an option

Comment: Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link breaks, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed, you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Super! +1 for the answer! :-)